# How to place icons for Text view based on some identity from service(Dot Net)

Tags: android

WE can place icons for buttons textview etc by using drawables.If i want to place icon based on some identity from service like service name

Answer (score 0):

You can place your icons on buttons by using following attributes
from xml:-

```
android:drawableRight
android:drwableLeft
android:drawableBottom
android:drawableTop
```

from programming(dynamically) :-

```
yourviewname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon, 0);
```